# Call Silverlight methods from Javascript by name

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to get a reference to a Silverlight method purely by name from Javascript, and then invoke it? With pure Javascript objects you would be something like this:

```
var f = theObj["theMethodName"];    
f.call(theObj, "an arg");
```

But treating a Silverlight object as an associative array doesn't seem work.

I'm guessing I could probably use Eval as a last resort, but I'd rather avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

The question is on how to call a Silverlight function from Javascript by name. You can easily call methods on an object directly by enabling a method for scripting [using the ScriptableMember attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), but you can't invoke it as a string directly.

I think you're stuck with eval.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("theMethodName", "An arg");

OR

var obj = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementByID("theObj");
obj.Invoke("theMethodName", "an Arg");

...

Ah, re-reading it...no, no access to the reflection API.  You'd have to expose it formally. Its still a managed object...just exposed as an 'object' in JScript.  So not the same as a prototype object.

Comment: AFAICT that's for calling Javascript from Silverlight. I'm going the other way - calling Silverlight from javascript

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
theObj["theMethodName"]("an arg");
```

But this does not:

```
theObj["theMethodName"].apply(null, "an arg");
```

at least I didn't manage to use apply (and call) :(